# Java BufferedImage not loading

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to write an imageloading function for my program, however it is doing something strange.

```
public void loadImage(BufferedImage img, String filepath) {
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(filepath));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

And I am calling it like so:

```
BufferedImage background = null;
loadImage(background, path);
```

I see in debugging that `img` loads properly, but `background` remains null the whole time and causes a `NullPointerException`.

When I change to a direct reference to background like `background = ImageIO.read(new File(filepath));` then it works just fine.

What's even more strange is that `System.out.println(img == background)` prints `true`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Java passes arguments by **value**, not reference. As far as Java is concerned,  `img` from `loadImage` has nothing to do with `background`.  All you did was pass over the address to whatever background refers to, not the reference `background` itself. `background` basically told the parameter `img`, "Hey, point at whatever I'm pointing at."

When you go

`img =  ImageIO.read(new File(filepath));`

You've just set `img` to refer to some new object, but background will still refer to whatever it was referring to before.

Instead, you should **return** the BufferedImage and set `background` to the return value, so something like

```
public BufferedImage loadImage(String filepath) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(new File(filepath));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
   return null;
}

background = loadImage(path);
```

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) has a little more info on the Pass-by-Value vs Pass-by-Reference issue in Java. Personally, the idea of the *value* of references being passed took me a while to get it through my head until I read [this article](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm).

Hope this helps.

---

As for your second note that `img == background` returns `true`, I'm not sure where you are checking this, but if you check it before `img = ImageIO...`, that will return true, because `img` and `background` both refer to `null`, since they are uninitialized.

`==`, when dealing with two Objects, will return true if and only if they both refer to the same object in memory, not if they are the same exact reference.